# trace-events.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

Хочу собрать ядро для своего телефона, чтобы пользоваться kali nethunter.

Смарт : honor 9 lite LLD-L31.

Исходники ядра : https://github.com/KingOfMezi/Kernel-Elemental.git (Исходники одного из кастомных ядер для смарта.)

В терминале запускаю make, идет компиляция,через некоторое время вылазит вот такая ошибка:

> ```
> In file included from fs/sdcardfs/trace-events.h:91,
>                  from fs/sdcardfs/main.c:18:
> include/trace/define_trace.h:83:42: fatal error: ./trace-events.h: No such file or directory
>  #include TRACE_INCLUDE(TRACE_INCLUDE_FILE)
>                                           ^
> compilation terminated.
> ```

Как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Там вообще то нужно запускать build.sh. Ви документацию читали?

Comment: Да,читал.Но при запуске все равно та же ошибка вылазит.

Comment: И еще ,почему то другие ядра (других телефонов )нормально собираются,для своего ни в какую не получается

Comment: и ядро патчили?

Comment: Да,файл zImage собирался как миленький,а вот для моего девайса эта ошибка постоянно выскакивает,какие бы исходники не использовал.

Comment: файл build.sh запускать надо,а вот какие пакеты устанавливать не нашел.